# Problem running google-chrome in the Terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, google-chrome

When running:

```
google-chrome
```

in the **Terminal**, I"m getting the following **error message**:

```
[3103:3103:0920/114029.496629:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

Despite the error message, the **Google Chrome** **browser opens without any problems**.

**What is the problem and what is the solution?**

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
OS Mode: Live USB drive with persistent storage

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem [more people are having](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/37423647?hl=en), I personally have it too:

```
$ google-chrome 
[45844:45844:1007/232622.863002:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

In the meantime, if you don't want this error message to appear again (since Google Chrome appears to work fine even with this supposed error), you can add this alias in your `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias google-chrome="google-chrome 2>/dev/null"
```

This alias makes the `google-chrome` command redirect (`>`) all its error output (`2`) to `/dev/null`. If you want the process to run in the background in the terminal, you can add a `&` at the end as well.